# Books with solutions for multivariable analysis/vector calculus

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I would like some recommendations to find problems with solutions, as I'm self-studying the course over the summer, to do with multivariable analysis for undergraduate level. My course's notes cover the following:

Differentiability of vector fields and scalar fields, Volume, line and surface integrals, Green, Stokes and Divergence theorems.

Method of Separation of variables on PDEs, Distributions (Test functions, Differentiation of Distributions, Tempered Distributions and their Fourier Transform, Hilbert spaces and linear operators, Green's functions for PDEs and ODEs, Storm-Liouville Theory.

Comment: Maybe of interested is which languages you are able, or confident to read?

Comment: Also you might want to search for "course xy through exercises" or something like that yourself.